# How to do a Desplegable List on JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i'm working on a proyect that requires a Deplegable list of routes of buses 
like    [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llHcH.png) I need that when the user clicks on any route, it unfolds a list with all the stations of that route. Also, when the user clicks on another route the previuos list fold it up and the route clicked unfolds. 
Is there any JavaFx Control that could do that?

Comment: My first thought would be to use a [`TreeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm). Another option might be to configure a `ListView` in such away that when a "master" item is selected, it can add/remove child elements - this is much more complicated

Comment: As pointed out by Erarnitox, you're probably looking for [`Accordion`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html). I recommend browsing the other classes in the `javafx.scene.control` package to familiarize yourself with available controls. There's also libraries out there, such as _ControlsFX_, which provide more controls. See https://github.com/mhrimaz/AwesomeJavaFX for a list of JavaFX-related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think it was called Accordeon. 
Make a list of these and you can get what you are looking for.